# Why the game view gets dark when play again button is clicked for replaying a scene in Unity 5.2?

Tags: unity-game-engine

when I reload a game scene by clicking on play again button in Unity , the game view automatically gets dark as if the skybox lighting settings are not set at all.

The game scene plays fine for the first time , the file was saved and when trying to replay the same again,the light settings go off. Is it a lighting bug in Unity 5 version?

Comment: Could you try and show us some of your code? I.e. anything to do with your lighting settings and how you restart your scene

Comment: @Canvas Hi.. For the first time when i play the scene , everything looks perfect . I verified by going into Window -> Lighting within Unity. The scene gets played . I stop and start it again , the whole environment goes dark within game view pane

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Posting a few pictures (or code) would help us to better understand the problem! Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about "stop and start it again". Do you mean that in the Unity editor, you stop the game by clicking the play button, then press it again to start? Or do you have a play button that you've coded in the game itself? I think most people here are assuming you've made an in-game button, but maybe you're talking about the editor. What do you do that resets the lighting back to normal? (Restarting Unity?)

Comment: @31eee384 Hi.. it is not an in-game button , i am talking about the unity editor , i stop and start the game by clicking the play button just to see how my game view works. For the first instance , the default light settings are fine, The issue happens when i stop and then start again and the default light goes off and gets dark in game view.

Comment: @NahuelIanni I will post a few pictures as early as possible. As i do not have it with me right now.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by unticking "Auto" (for automatic baking of light maps) in Window>Lighting>Scene and clicking "Build".

[The same problem is answered on the Unity website](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/925671/very-weird-dark-level-loading.html)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the answer . Works for me now.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Turn off Baked Global Illumination in Mixed Lighting section.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are `Destroy()`ing objects you are not supposed to destroy.
You might for example have this case:

```
public class LightInstantiator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject lightPrefab;
    private GameObject mySceneLight;

    void Start()
    {
        mySceneLight = Instantiate(lightPrefab);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        DestroyImmediate(lightPrefab); // BUG: you destroy the Prefab instead of the instance
    }
}
```

This example script instantiates the Scene light for me, and destroys it again when itself is destroyed. This is perfectly legit, but I accidentally have introduced a bug: where I meant to destroy the instantiated light (mySceneLight) I actually destroy the Prefab.

On first start everything seems fine, light and all. When stopping and restarting the scene however, Unity will feed the (previously destroyed) Prefab into my script, which will then be unable to instantiate a functioning light: the scene stays dark.

Something along these lines happened to me once. I don't know if this is still possible, but it might be worth a check.

**Afterthought:**

It may even be easier. You might accidentally modify the prefab light in code by setting its intensity to 0 during your first run. As it is a prefab, Unity might not reset that, and on your second run, the prefab light intensity is still 0.

Comment: Thanks for the script. But in my game view , i used only the default ambient light setup skybox. Maybe i should check some settings in Unity editor  (Menu Window -> lighting) . Please advise.